# Cross validation for polynomial kernel in LibSVM, using Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, libsvm, svm

I am using LibSVM with Python. Prior to building my classifier, I want to plot the average error of cross validation for different values of `d` and `C` to find the best `(d, C)` combination in terms of average accuracy. I wrote a Python script to cross-validate for a particular `d, C` value and the output for each of the ten iterations of my cross-validation appeared on the screen. I have 2 problems now:

1. How to write a Python script that takes in variables for `d` and `C` values as parameters in the `svm_parameter` function. `svm_parameter('-d dval')` gives the error:

   ```
   ValueError : invalid literal for int() with base 10:dval
   ```
2. How to record the output data - I can't find a way to save the accuracy for each classification unless I manually copy it from the UNIX screen. Is there a way to access and save the output file?

Thank you. I am new to Python.

Comment: Solved part 1 using the values returned by svm_predict and writing them to a file in Python. Still need help on dealing with the ValueError

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend to use the excellent [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) library for your task. It also has a wrapper for LibSVM (see [svm.SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)), but in addition gives you all the necessary tools for [cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/cross_validation.html), finding optimal d and C with [grid-search](http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/modules/grid_search.html), easy way to measure accuracy with the metrics module and a huge number of other useful tools.

Regarding the valuerror, python attempts to cast the string dval into an integer. You probably want to do something like `svm_parameter('-d %s' % dval)`, if `dval` is the variable holding the value of `d`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have time right now to figure out a new environment. A fix for the ValueError would solve my problem at the moment. I will consider at the sklearn library in the future, thanks!

Comment: Added an explanation for the valuerror in the answer, hope that helps